# Tomcat external server doesn't start my spring boot application with /jdk17 and /windows 11

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, war, java-17

Tomcat external server runs, but doesn't start my spring-boot application, even when I check the logs I don't see the spring-boot log Started this one : I tried many solution and I mentioned everythin I did bellow

:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

After creating the war file with the following properties and dependencies :
-External tomcat version :
`apache-tomcat-9.0.75`
-Packaging and properties:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
```

-Tomcat dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I changed the final file name :
`<finalName>wmm</finalName>` 
Also I extended the SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WhereIsMyMoneyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WhereIsMyMoneyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WhereIsMyMoneyApplication.class);
    }
```

I believe Im using the correct path to use the application:
`http://localhost:8080/wmm/{....}`
-I have set the envirement for the JDK17 and the path variable also
-And whenever I run the "catalina.bat run" command or "startup.bat", the server work perfectly on `http://localhost:8080`
-I checked the list of application on "localhost/manager/html" it shows that the application exists in application list
-Also I tried to deploy it manualy with the Tomcat manager UI by uploading the war file and deploying it but it shows the following error :
Message:
**FAIL - War file [wmm.war] already exists on server**
I think I have set everything correct, tried many solutions but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring Boot 3 and Spring framework 6, the minimum requirement is JDK17 and Tomcat 10 due to the changes of the packages from javax ( that are in Tomcat 9 ) to jakarta ( Tomcat 10 ).

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it with tomcat 10 and it works perfectly, you saved my life